# How to stop custom url being redirected to homepage?

Tags: .htaccess, web

Question - I have custom url say **abc.com/page/?name=test&address=test**.  once copy-pasted in browser gets auto redirected to abc.com homepage. How to stop this auto-redirection in chrome or any browser?

Comment: Do you have .htaccess rules for `/page`? If not, that could be your problem.

Comment: Can this be handled on client side?

Comment: `Can this be handled on client side?`; No if it is happening on server side. You should place your current .htaccess in question and also test from a new browser to rule out browser cache

Comment: @Rock No, this is a something that can only be handled server-side. You need to create an .htaccess file and specify the page rules using `mod_rewrite`. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an `.htaccess` file and use `mod_rewrite` to remove the file extension and create pretty URLs.

Something like the following to give you an idea, but you'll need to tailor the rules to suit your app's particular needs. Just Google "mod_rewrite" or "htaccess pretty" and you'll find tons of articles.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L,QSA]
```